# Error while starting Spring boot application with external JAR containing the beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot Application created from the Spring Initializer, I added an external JAR (manually in build path libraries) who containing the beans. The beans are annotated with @Entity and @json...
The problem is that when starting the application I have the error below. ***If I copy the beans into the project as a simple bean, the project start correctly.***

**Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.xxxxxxx.domain.User**

Please any help is greatly appreciated

Here is an example of a bean from the JAR.

---

```
    package org.xxxxxxx.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
@Entity
@Table (name="userTable", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"nom"}))
public class User implements Serializable {
    
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="nom", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String name;
    private String motsdepasse;
    private String token;
    @ManyToOne
    private UserGroupe groupe;
    
//  @Column(columnDefinition="boolean default false")
    private boolean desactive;
    
//  @Column(columnDefinition="boolean default false")
    private boolean finalPwd;
    
    private boolean deleted;
    
    private Date datePassword;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Branch branche;
     //getters + setters
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all packages below your main configuration class (the one annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication) will be searched. You can customize entity scanning locations using the @EntityScan annotation:

[spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-entity-classes)

Comment: I already use this solution but always the same exception is generated.